# Straight strands of hair when I change up the display amount

Tags: particles, hair

I'm currently following a CGCookie tutorial series on how to create realistic hair and I encountered this problem:

The children will follow the parent strand of hair correctly if the display amount is set to 100 or less, but they will turn straight when I bump it up to 500, for example. Here are some screenshots:
[image: Strands with no children visible]
[image: Children display amount set to 100]
[image: Children display amount set to 500]

[image: Scalp only mesh with children set to 100]

[image: Scalp only mesh with children set to 500]

Comment: Have you tried changing the Children to Interpolated mode instead of Simple?

Comment: Yes, it actually gets worse, the hair becomes straight from the root all the way down to the bottom